# Can we use frontdoor.jsp to give access to salesforce vf page, without using username and password?

Tags: single-sign-on, authentication

If the SSO is set up, can we use frontdoor.jsp without using Username password? I would like to access the second salesforce org from first salesforce org. SSO has been set up already. Canvas application does not serve the purpose because it will not give access to standard record detail page.Existing code below, uses username, password and we would like to avoid using that.

```
private static String login(String un,String pw,String 
                                         domain){
        HttpRequest request = new HttpRequest();
        request.setEndpoint('https://' + domain + 
              '.salesforce.com/services/Soap/u/30.0');
        request.setMethod('POST');
        request.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/xml;charset=UTF-8');
        request.setHeader('SOAPAction', '""');
        request.setBody('<Envelope xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><Header/><Body><login xmlns="urn:partner.soap.sforce.com"><username>' + un + '</username><password>' + pw + '</password></login></Body></Envelope>');
        Http h = new Http();
        HttpResponse res = h.send(request);        
        return res.getBody();
    }



    String loginRes = createLoginRequest(username,password,domain);
        if(!String.isBlank(loginRes) && !loginRes.containsIgnoreCase('INVALID_LOGIN')){
            Dom.Document loginDoc = new Dom.Document();
            loginDoc.load(loginRes);
            Dom.XmlNode resultElmt = loginDoc.getRootElement()
              .getChildElement('Body','http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/')
              .getChildElement('loginResponse','urn:partner.soap.sforce.com')
              .getChildElement('result','urn:partner.soap.sforce.com');

            /*Get the session Id and Server url*/
            String serverurl = resultElmt.getChildElement('serverUrl','urn:partner.soap.sforce.com').getText().split('/services')[0];
            String sessionId = resultElmt.getChildElement('sessionId','urn:partner.soap.sforce.com').getText();

            /*Use frontdoor.jsp to login to salesforce*/
            loginReference =  new Pagereference(serverurl+'/secur/frontdoor.jsp?sid='+sessionId+'&retURL=https://SALESFORCEURL/apex/myVFpage?id='+abcId);
            //loginReference =  new Pagereference(serverurl+'/secur/frontdoor.jsp?sid='+sessionId+'&retURL=https://NA999.salesforce.com/'+abcId);

        }
        else{
            Apexpages.addMessage(new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.ERROR,'Username or Password Incorrect'));
        }
   }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

frontdoor.jsp works with a session ID. To obtain the session ID, you have to provide a credential when authenticating to Salesforce. Often this credential is a username/password pair as your code sample shows.

If SSO is set up between two orgs, you don't need frontdoor.jsp.

Comment: Thank you identigral! If SSO is set up, what can I use to achieve this functionality?

Comment: Can I just use URL redirects to the other org?

Comment: @Suraj Yes, try that

Comment: Thanks a lot! I will try it and let you know!!

Comment: I tried that. Unfortunately it is taking the user to login screen.
Code below
`public Pagereference login(){
     Pagereference loginReference;
     currentRecordId  = ApexPages.CurrentPage().getparameters().get('id');
    getId = [query];
     loginRef =  new Pagereference('INSTANCE.visual.force.com/apex/VFPAGE?id='+getId);
     return loginRef;
     }
     }`

Comment: Sounds like SSO isn't working or perhaps it's working, the devil is in the details.

Comment: SSO is perfect. I am sure about that. May be my controller is wrong ?

Comment: Possibly. Post another question regarding the controller.

Comment: Good ideal Integral

Comment: As per your suggestion. Thanks for making me udnerstand the real usage of frontdoor.jsp
 https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/261277/how-to-bypass-login-page-in-url-redirects-after-sso-setup